# CORS issues. Github pages -> Heroku

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, cors

I'm running into classic cors issue, that I cannot solve.

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'xxx/current_user' from origin 'https://username.github.io' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

I obviously installed cors in my Node.js app and use proper headers. Here's how my index.js looks like:

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors')
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const passport = require('passport');
const cookieSession = require('cookie-session');

const keys = require('./config/keys');


require('./models/user');
require('./services/passport');

mongoose.connect(keys.mongoUri, { useNewUrlParser: true })

const app = express();

app.use(cors())
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.use(
    cookieSession({
        maxAge: 30 * 24 + 60 * 60 * 1000, //30 days
        keys: [keys.cookieKey]
    })
);

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", '*');
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", true);
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS');
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", 'Origin,X-Requested-With,Content-Type,Accept,content-type,application/json');
    next();
});

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

//ROUTES
require('./routes/auth')(app);
require('./routes/game')(app);

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(PORT);
```

And my basic test call to API inside my react app looks like this:

```
export const checkAuth = () => dispatch => {
    axios.get('/current_user').then(res => {
        if (res.data) {

        }
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log({ err })
    })
}
```

Am I missing something obvious?

[image: Headers for 1st request]

[image: Headers for 2nd request]

Code for current_user route

```
 app.get('/current_user', (req, res) => {
        res.send(req.user)
    })
```

Comment: where/how is your server being configured?

Comment: @WillJenkins However Heroku is doing it

Comment: Why are you manually adding headers to the response? You're using the `cors` middleware library, and you have fixed values: create a `corsOptions = {...}` and pass that into `app.use(cors(corsOptions))`, so the cors middleware "just works" for all requests. And you'll want to use a whitelist of cleared sites: don't use `*` unless you want to grant access to the entire internet O_o

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Im doing it this way because passing origins to corsOptions didnt solve anything, thats why I started manually adding headers. Didnt fix anything though, I wish that whole internet could access it, but for now nobody can

Comment: You'll have to show more code: you're showing code for a GET, but an error that talks about a preflight failure: GET requests don't use preflighting, only POST and related verbs do, so this is almost certainly not the code that's triggering the error. What does your network tab show?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Updated post with error for this particular get. Sure, there is nothing about preflight, but the rest is basically the same.

Comment: And can you show us what your network tab shows when you look at that request? what headers do you get back? (And what additional information does the network tab give you that might help you, and us, figure out what might be wrong) Also, you're not showing the actual resolution for `get_current_user`, so it's impossible to say whether or not there might be anything else interfering. (A [mcve] is a good idea at this point)

Comment: Is this what you wanted? Network tab doesnt show anything more, other tabs are empty ("Failed to load response data")

Comment: NO NEED to use Cors package if you append the headers yourself. Are you sure this is a cors error? What is telling you that ?

Comment: @BorisDetry Error in the console. I know it's strange, I added headers myself, then tried adding cors package, then both and it did not help. I have no problem when I open this project locally, but once its in production it gives this error

Comment: @MazMat you are maybe runnig your server over another server (apache for example)? I could also be firewall routes!

Comment: You're whitelisting every origin so there really is no point using cors on your server. Just remove it.

Comment: @Chase As mentioned before I tried every configuration, also my removing everything. No help. I start to think it's heroku issue

Comment: I checked your server, it seems to be unavailable (error 503) maybe your server is crashed?

Comment: @MojtabaIzadmehr According to that its running http://prntscr.com/p19vqn  Besides, if it wasnt I wouldnt get cors error but other one

Answer (score 0):

CORS can be present on client application as well as server side requested url. you should have

```
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", '*');
```

in your client application as well on github.
and you have it 
try this way use CURL

```
curl -i https://api.github.com -H "Origin: http://example.com"
```

HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: ETag, Link, X-GitHub-OTP, X-RateLimit-Limit, X-RateLimit-Remaining, X-RateLimit-Reset, X-OAuth-Scopes, X-Accepted-OAuth-Scopes, X-Poll-Interval

This should work.
That means api.github.com  is CORS accesible.
**but when  you will put  'https://username.github.io'** 
it will give error as it is github page and has CORS restricted
So if you enable Access-Control-Allow-Origin on GitHub also it may work.
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", '*');

Answer (score 0):

From what I remember with CORS

when you use:

`"Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", true`

You need to specify the domain you allow, and not use a wildcard

Bad:

`Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`

Good:

`Access-Control-Allow-Origin: yoursite.com`

On your node backend you can maybe use this:

`request.header('Referer')`

Answer (score 0):

In my experience of configuring CORS in fastify server worked after a restart of the computer. Your code seems correct, although it is a bad idea to setup CORS with default configuration. In my case also I have configured CORS properly. After a lot of time trying with different but correct configurations, it worked only after a system restart.

My guess is that somehow the system remembered the initial requests made while CORS was not setup. So, the restart fixed that and everything worked as expected.

Or you can try from some other machine, if you do not want to restart.